# Replace "< -" keystroke combination for a custom shortcut in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, shortcut

I was wondering how could I set a shortcut, for example <kbd>CRTL+F</kbd> for the keystrokes `<-` for a better experience programming with R language. Or even when I type `-` it prints out on my coding scripts the full `<-`.

I could set it in RStudio but couldn't find a way to do that in VS code. The shortcut options in VS Code are always linked to IDE commands, didn't help me at all.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or use this handy keyboard shortcut example with arguments from the doc pages

```
  {
    "key": "ctrl+f",
    "command": "type",
    "args": { "text": "<-" },
    "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == r"
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also define a user snippet. For example, put this in your `snippets\r.json` file:

```
"assign": {
    "prefix": "=",
    "body": " <- ",
    "description": "left arrow assignment"
}
```

Now, typing <kbd>=</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> will insert `<-`.

Answer (score 0):

Got it just by adding the below code to `keybinding.json` file:

```
// Place your key bindings in this file to override the defaults
[
  {
    "key": "oem_minus oem_minus",
    "command": "type",
    "args": {
      "text": "<-"
    },
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
  }
]
```

Worked perfectly. When I type `--` it prints out `<-`.

Comment: also add a languageId compare in the `when` clause. You will be surprised when you write a C/C++/Java/JavaScript/... program

Comment: How could I do that? I want this transformation only in R. Could your help me?

Comment: Yeah, you definitely want that `when` clause, you don't want this replacement when you're writing C++ code